# Regex help, need to remove "table" item

Tags: regex

```
"foo" { 
    foo = "bar"
    foo2 = "bar2"
    foo3 = "bar3"
    foo4 = "bar4"
    id = "1"
    foo5 = "bar5"
}
"foo" { 
    foo = "bar"
    foo2 = "bar2"
    foo3 = "bar3"
    foo4 = "bar4"
    id = "2"
    foo5 = "bar5"
}
"foo" { 
    foo = "bar"
    foo2 = "bar2"
    foo3 = "bar3"
    foo4 = "bar4"
    id = "3"
    foo5 = "bar5"
}
...
```

I have regex for selecting this table item by their id, but it also selects everything forward him, when I need it to stop when first "}" was found. And I don't know how to prevent this.

My regex is: `/^"(?P<title>[^"]*)"[^{]*{(?=(.*))(?=[^}]*\sid\s*=\s+"2"[^}])/ixsmg`

https://regex101.com/r/xA9kG3/26

Comment: Oh god, It's been so simple for you and so not obvious for me.. Thanks, Chris!

Comment: `ixsmg`: Using all modifiers of the world doesn't increase your chances to find the good pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` is consuming too much. You need to tell it to stop at the first match AND tell it what that match is based on.

```
^"(?P<title>[^"]*)"[^{]*{
                    (?=(.*?}))
                    (?=[^}]*\sid\s*=\s+"2"[^}])
```

This will have it stop at the first `}`. If you ever have `{}` inside this string structure this won't work.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xA9kG3/27